# .Net Regex to parse specific JSON format

Tags: .net, vb.net, regex, json

I'm writing a little web service which generates SO/SF/SU/MSO user flair in the form of an image with various "themes". I find this preferable to using the HTML/JS solutions offered by SO as it's more flexible and also works better in forum signatures.

I'm retrieving the data using the apparently unofficial API ([More info here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/17037/unofficial-so-api-reference/17040#17040)). I can have the data in HTML or JSON. I assumed the JSON would be easier to parse.

Unfortunately, I'm not great at regexes. and the best I can come up with is some very hacky sub-stringing. I believe a regex should be the most elegant solution but would welcome other suggestions.

Can someone please point me in the right direction for a regex that matches
ID, GravatarURL, ProfileURL, DisplayName, Reputation and Badge Counts (Bronze/Silver/Gold).

FWIW This is to be used in a VB.Net project (in case that affects the syntax at all)

```
{"id":1,"gravatarHtml":"\u003cimg src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8?s=50&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG\" height=\"50\" width=\"50\" alt=\"\"\u003e","profileUrl":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood","displayName":"Jeff Atwood","reputation":"18,446","badgeHtml":"\u003cspan title=\"8 gold badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge1\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e8\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"57 silver badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge2\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e57\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan title=\"72 bronze badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge3\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e72\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e"}
```

or a slightly more readable format:

```
{
"id":1,
"gravatarHtml":"\u003cimg src=\"http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/51d623f33f8b83095db84ff35e15dbe8?s=50&amp;d=identicon&amp;r=PG\" height=\"50\" width=\"50\" alt=\"\"\u003e",
"profileUrl":"http://stackoverflow.com/users/1/jeff-atwood",
"displayName":"Jeff Atwood",
"reputation":"18,446",
"badgeHtml":"
    \u003cspan title=\"8 gold badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge1\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e8\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e
    \u003cspan title=\"57 silver badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge2\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e57\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e
    \u003cspan title=\"72 bronze badges\"\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badge3\"\u003e&#9679;\u003c/span\u003e\u003cspan class=\"badgecount\"\u003e72\u003c/span\u003e\u003c/span\u003e
"
}
```

(NB: It's worth noting that if you don't have any of a certain badge, there's no entry for that badge at all rather than showing a "0")

Unfortunately, I don't even know where to start with the regex so any help, suggestions or documentation greatly appreciated

[Edit]

In case any of you are interested, some screenshots of the flair as a work in progress are available here: [Me](http://www.soware.co.uk/StackOverflow/Basiclife.JPG), [Jeff Atwood](http://www.soware.co.uk/StackOverflow/JeffAtwood.JPG), [Joel Spolsky](http://www.soware.co.uk/StackOverflow/JoelSpolsky.JPG)

I'll make it publicly accessible if anyone wants their own?

[/Edit]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you considered using [**stackexchange-api**](http://code.google.com/p/stackexchange-api/wiki/ExampleCodeV4)

Here is the code sample for what you are trying to achive

```
        User JeffAtwood =
          User.GetUserWithId(123456, StackExchangeSite.StackOverflow);

        long ID = JeffAtwood.Id;
        Uri gravatarHtml = JeffAtwood.Gravatar;
        String name = JeffAtwood.Name;           
        List<ReputationChange> repGraph = 
            JeffAtwood.ReputationGraph[DateTime.Now.AddDays(-3), DateTime.Now].ToList();
        long totalReputations = JeffAtwood.Reputation;
        List<Badge> badges = JeffAtwood.Badges.ToList();
         .
         .
```

---

There are hundreds of other bits you can get using simple built-in methods, other than Requesting and then parsing through Json response.

And for  parsing the Jason Response, best library to use is

- [**Json.Net**](http://www.codeplex.com/Json)

Comment: As well as answering my question, you solved the problem behind it. Many Thanks. I had no idea that API existed - definitely going to be a boon.

Comment: hope to see a stunning Add-in for SOF soon!!

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't use regex to parse JSON. Like HTML, JSON is not a regular language, and thus regexes won't be able to truly parse it - only provide a poor approximation, which can easily lead to headaches down the road.

Instead, you probably want to look into JSON parsers like [`JavaScriptSerializer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.javascriptserializer.aspx) or [Json.NET](http://james.newtonking.com/pages/json-net.aspx).

Comment: Thanks - That's a much better than a regex and useful to know